# Can I define all requests via web.xml to servlet something like /*?

Tags: jakarta-ee

So I want to handle All requests to Servlet. But if I put wildcard /* in my web.xml then get infinite loop in:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

And I want all my requests not to end with .jsp but rather with like /main, /main/level, /main/level/1 etc. 
Question is How to avoid infinite loop there?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>main.Main</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out that if I want to handle all requests through servlet I can create my Filter where then I can use

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>main</filter-name>
    <filter-class>main.Main</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>main</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

After that I can pass `req` and `resp` objects to who I want.